# Where is ImmutableArray?

Tags: c#, immutable-collections

Why does [ImmutableArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) seem to not be there in Microsoft Immutable Collections NuGet package version [1.0.34](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable/1.0.34)?

[image]

Comment: It probably does not have a public constructor and you have to use a factory method to build it.

Comment: @leppie is right, as a single google search will show you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn638264(v=vs.111).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1, but I would just use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn628186(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: I can't find the whole class. I would edit the post to remove the "new" from the image but cannot find the "edit" link (maybe not enough reputation or it's just not my day today :)

Comment: @thromius: Do not pay attention to these comments - if `new` was context sensitive, why would it show interfaces? I just checked - in auto-completion, static classes still show up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ImmutableArray` is not present in your version of the library.

As you can see in the [version history](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/immutable.aspx), the release notes for 1.1.20 mention "Re-included ImmutableArray<T>"

You can find the explanation for why ImmutableArray was absent from the 1.0 version on the .NET blog, in this [announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/12/immutable-collections-are-now-rc.aspx). (In short - the Roslyn team had a noticeable performance hit when they tried to use that type instead of regular arrays, and the team in charge of the library was not sure how to fix that, while keeping a reasonable API.)

You will find newer versions of the library under its new NuGet package, [`System.Collections.Immutable`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable).

N.B.: According to the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray%601.cs) in the new versions of `System.Collections.Immutable`, they have apparently decided to take the API hit - that is, some operations on a unitialized `ImmutableArray` will throw a surprising `NullReferenceException`s. Clearly, `ImmutableArray` should *never* be instantiated with `new`. (`ImmutableArray<T>.Empty` should be used instead)

Comment: Interesting information in the announcement you linked to - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray%28v=vs.111%29.aspx):

```
public static class ImmutableArray
```

The `ImmutableArray` is *static*, so you can't instantiate it. Use:

```
ImmutableArray.Create<T>(); // Creates an empty immutable array
```

Comment: Did you try this? I mean, for me the whole ImmutableArray class doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: You are right, @jean-hominal has the answer to why it's not present. I'm also missing it in my package. But as for creation, my answer stands. ;)

Comment: Except that you *can* create an `ImmutableArray<T>` with `new ImmutableArray<T>` - but the only one that can be created that way is empty. (Reminder: every `struct` defines a zero-arguments constructor that cannot be redefined)