# Missing method System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray

Tags: c#, f#, benchmarkdotnet

I am using BenchmarkDotNet to benchmark F# code. Everything works fine if I run the benchmark from console aplication:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<BinomialBenchmark>();
```

For some quick tests, I wanted to run the benchmark from F# interactive window and here I get the following exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Byte> System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader.GetBlobContent(System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobHandle)'.
```

It seems that historically this constructor was removed and added back into Collections.Immutable library, but I am using the latest version (1.3) and it should be in. See: [Where is ImmutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273466/where-is-immutablearray)

Furthermore this works fine when running the console application. I thought the issue might be in the versions of referenced libraries, so I went over all BenchmarkDotNet related references in my console application and check that I reference the same ones in FSX:

```
#r "../packages/BenchmarkDotNet/lib/net45/BenchmarkDotNet.dll"
#r "../packages/BenchmarkDotNet.Core/lib/net45/BenchmarkDotNet.Core.dll"
#r "../packages/BenchmarkDotNet.Toolchains.Roslyn/lib/net45/BenchmarkDotNet.Toolchains.Roslyn.dll"
#r "../packages/BenchmarkDotNet.Diagnostics.Windows/lib/net45/BenchmarkDotNet.Diagnostics.Windows.dll"

#r "../packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/lib/net45/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll"
#r "../packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common/lib/net45/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll" 

#r "../packages/System.Reflection.Metadata/lib/netstandard1.1/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll"
#r "../packages/System.Collections.Immutable/lib/netstandard1.0/System.Collections.Immutable.dll"
#r "../packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/lib/netstandard1.0/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"
```

I made sure the exact versions are used in the console application. It seems that the some libraries used by the F# interactive runtime are not the same as the once used by the console application.

It seems that similar issue occurs with LinqPad:
https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/66

Any hint would be appritiated.

Comment: Could you create an issue in the repo on GitHub? We will try to fix it in the next versions of the library.

Comment: As requested, I have created the issue on github for this:
https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/316
let me know if it is missing any details